# Issues with my simple 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to make a basic 2d array with rows and columns in Java using netbeans 8.1.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int temp = 5;
    int temp2 = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < temp2; ++i)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < temp; ++k)
        {
            System.out.println("|_|");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

But for some reason, the output looks like this:

[image: output]

Could someone help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: Do you know the difference between println and print?

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much! I didn't notice that. Must've done it out of habit haha.

Comment: If your issue is revolved, please tag the answer as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you should be using `print` in combination with `println`, see below:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int temp = 5;
    int temp2 = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < temp2; ++i)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < temp; ++k)
        {
            System.out.print("|_|"); //Prints each cell one after another in the same row.
        }
        System.out.println(""); //Prints a new row, .println("\n") will print two new rows.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [dat3450's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43905086/7573818) to be enough to resolve your issue, but the `System.out.println("");` irked me a little bit.
So, that's how I'd do it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int temp = 5;
    int temp2 = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < temp2; ++i)
    {
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for(int k = 0; k < temp; ++k)
        {
            row.append("|_|");  //concat the cells in the same String
        }
        System.out.println(row.toString()); //prints one entire row at a time
    }
}
```